# drf custom response to override Response()

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm using DRF and to return response, I used `Response()` which located at `from rest_framework.response import Response`

To make custom response, first, I copied all of the source to custom file.

And in my views, I changed `Response()` to my own file.

But when I running django server and access via web, it through errors.

`AssertionError: .accepted_renderer not set on Response`

I just copied original `Repsonse()` and re-use it.

Why it occur errors?

Purpose of custom response is I want to add more argument that something likes cursor for pagination.

As you know that in original Response, takes 6 arguments.

```
def __init__(self, data=None, status=None,
             template_name=None, headers=None,
             exception=False, content_type=None):
```

And return it in `def rendered_content(self)`, line of `ret = renderer.render(self.data, accepted_media_type, context)`

So my scenario is, add `cursor` to `__init__` and pass through it to `renderer.render()`.

Any problem with my way?

Thanks.

Comment: can you show the ***complete*** view code?

Comment: @JPG Just copied original `Response`'s code and use it. But it throw errors.

Comment: Can you brife, what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @JPG I want to add more argument to `Response()` and rendering it.

Comment: can you explain the use-case?

Comment: @JPG I will add pagination information. I know there is already `Pagination` class in django, But in my case, I will do not use that.